# Gridelements: Coloured Frames with external TS-Definitions

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-gridelements

in the flexform of the backend layouts of gridelements is on option for coloured frames (neutral, red, blue, green). Is there a possibility to get coloured frames for my grids when i define the different grids not in the database but in external TS-files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for the `frame` parameter.

```
title = Full Width
description = Content uses full width of page
frame = 3
icon = EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Images/grid-icons/grid-1col.png
```

`frame` can have these values:

- `1` => Red
- `2` => Green
- `3` => Blue